# SQLITE fill value with unique random table

Tags: sqlite, random, uniqueidentifier

I want to create a table with a field that is unique and limited to a certain value. Lets say that the limit is 100, the table is full, I remove a random row, and when I create a new row it has the value that was freed before.
It doesn't need to be the fastest thing in the world (the limit is quite small), I just want to implement it in a DB.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does everything in a trigger, so you can just use a normal INSERT.

For the table itself, we use an autoincrementing ID column:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name);
```

We need another table to store an ID temporarily:

```
CREATE TABLE moriturus(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_DeleteAndReorder
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) > 100
BEGIN
    -- first, select a random record to be deleted, and save its ID
    DELETE FROM moriturus;
    INSERT INTO moriturus
      SELECT ID FROM MyTable
      WHERE ID <> NEW.ID
      ORDER BY random()
      LIMIT 1;

    -- then actually delete it
    DELETE FROM MyTable
      WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
                  FROM moriturus);

    -- then change the just inserted record to have that ID
    UPDATE MyTable
      SET ID = (SELECT ID
                FROM moriturus)
      WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create one more column in main table, say `deleted` (integer, 0 or 1). When you need to delete with certain id, do not really delete it, but simply update `deleted` to 1:

```
UPDATE mytable SET deleted=1 WHERE id = <id_to_delete>
```

When you need to insert, find id to be reused:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE deleted LIMIT 1
```

If this query returns empty result, then use INSERT to create new id. Otherwise, simply update your row:

```
UPDATE mytable SET deleted=0, name='blah', ... WHERE id=<id_to_reuse>
```

All queries reading from your main table should have `WHERE` constraint with `NOT deleted` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOT deleted
```

If you add index on `deleted`, this method should work fast even for large number of rows.

Comment: Thanks if that doesn't work for my case it should lead me in the right direction.